# Should i force memoization?

Tags: php, design-patterns, memoization

I see myself doing this a lot:

```
function getTheProperty()
{
    if (! isset($this->theproperty)) {
       $property = // logic to initialise thepropery
       $this->theproperty = $property;
    }
    return $this->theproperty;
}
```

This is good, since it avoids the epxensive logic used to initialise the value.  however, the downside so far as i can see is that i cant determine exactly how clients will use this and this may be confusing.

Is this a good pattern to use?  What considerations should be taking when doing this?

How about adding a parameter - $forceNew for example that bypasses the memoization?

Answer (score 0):

[Magic Methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get). Something like:

```
Class MyMagic {

  private $initinfo = array(
    'foo' => array('someFunction', array('arg1', 'arg2'))
    'bar' => array(array($this, 'memberFunction'), array('arg3'))
  );

  public function __get($name) {
    if( ! isset($this->$name) ) {
      if( isset($this->initinfo[$name]) ) {
        $this->$name = call_user_func_array(initinfo[$name][0], initinfo[$name][1]);
      } else {
        throw new Exception('Property ' . $name . 'is not defined.');
      }
    } else {
      return $this->$name;
    }
  }

}

$magic = new MyMagic();
echo $magic->foo; //echoes the return of: someFunction('arg1', 'arg2')
echo $magic->bar; //echoes the return of: $this->memberFunction('arg3')
```

Comment: Expensive in terms of requiring a lot of work/time to intialise the value.  Perhaps a large db read, api call etc.

Comment: @MartyWallace yeah I just read up on memoization [I thought that was a typo] let me re-write this answer.

Comment: As an add-on to this answer; It's considered best practice to hide the details of how a class operates. Using the magic method helps accomplish this by hiding the functions the class uses internally. However, this should generally only be done if there's a corresponding __get function or direct access to the property afterwards. "If it looks like a property, it should act like a property", so if it's read-only or a result based on an operation it may be better to stick with a getter function. Otherwise, your code looks good.

Comment: For adding parameters, it should be avoided if unnecessary. When designing a class and its functions, you should design them under the assumption that they'll be abused and misused. For example: if you have the forceNew parameter, you should assume at some point it might wind up in a loop and kill performance. Also, if you add a parameter now, you may want to add another later; if that happens the boolean value will be a constant pain.

Comment: @MartyWallace updated. I know there's another function similar to `call_user_func()` that takes objects as arguments, but I can't remember or find it atm. edit: nvm, it was just the structure of `callable`s, updated again.